# Best practice for looping through a nested array php

Tags: php, loops

I am writing in PHP.

What I am trying to do is something like a configurable product in Magento2 or variable product in Woocommerce. I am asking the user to enter attributes to the product, like color, size, etc'.

Think of each attribute as a attribute category which contains attributes inside it, e.g 'color' will have attributes like 'red', 'green', 'blue' and so on. Size will have attributes like 'large', 'small', 'medium' and so on.

Now, I need to make a loop which takes all sizes, colors and other chosen attributes and returns all the possible configurations. At the same time the amount of attributes to loop through isn't predefined since the user can add or remove attributes.

For example if I have this:

```
Color - - - - - - - - Size - - - - - - - - Shape
Red - - - - - - - - - Large - - - - - - -  Square
Green - - - - - - - - Medium - - - - - - - Rounded
Blue - - - - - - - -  Small - - - - - - - -
```

So I will have to have every color with every size and shape:

```
Red - Large - Square
Red - Large - Rounded
Red - Medium - Square
Red - Medium - Rounded
Red - Small - Square
Red - Small - Rounded
```

And the same with the other attributes.

What is the best practice to achive it?

Comment: It's overkill to list all possible combinations with 10+ attributes, the user will turn mad. You know what? For each attribute, put a `<select>` list on the page and the user will select what he wants... Problem solved

Comment: @ThanhTrung The user have a check box for selecting which attributes he wants to use. I need to make it possible to output every configuration because in a shop, a product with different colors has a different SKU and hence I have to have that option

Comment: What do you want as return value? An array of string dash separated or a complex structure of array?

Comment: @ThanhTrung I want it to be a string in that pattern: `attr-1 - attr-2 - attr-n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need recursion for this.

```
function getCombinations($attributes){
    $combinations = [];
    buildCombinationChain($attributes,0,[],$combinations);

    // encode combinations to desired string format
    $result = [];
    foreach ($combinations as $combination) {
        $result[] = implode(' - ', $combination);
    }

    return $result;
}

function buildCombinationChain($attributes,$index,$chain,&$output){
    if($index>=count($attributes)){
        // we have reached the last attribute, stop recursion and push the current chain to the output array
        $output[] = $chain;
        return;
    }
    foreach ($attributes[$index] as $attribute) {
        $new_chain = $chain; // create a copy of the current chain
        $new_chain[] = $attribute; // and add the current attribute to it
        buildCombinationChain($attributes,$index+1,$new_chain,$output); // continue recursively on the next attribute group
    }
}



$attributes = [
    ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue'],
    ['Large', 'Medium', 'Small'],
    ['Square', 'Rounded']
];

echo json_encode(getCombinations($attributes));
```

Comment: First of all thanks (alot! :D). Secondly, how can I upload each combination to a database while each field in the column will contain 1 combination from the above?

Comment: @Omer create two tables, one for the product itself and one containing a row for each of the product's attributes (key-value) pointing to the id of the product row.